# Cannot find xpath double URL page refresh

Tags: selenium

I am running a selenium script where I log into a website. When I log into the website the page goes out to two different urls. As soon as the first url loads I get an error saying it cannot find my xpath. However, the page just hasn't loaded yet. How should I handle the web page going out to multiple URL's before I want it to wait to see my xpath?

Comment: Can you share your code and error message you  are getting ? Also indicate at what location you are getting error. It will be easy to debug then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Fluent Wait to wait until URL is the expected one

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).Until(ExpectedConditions.UrlToBe("your-last-url"));
```

where driver is your driver instance (chrome, firefox, ie etc).

In this case, if any error/redirect will occur, won't affect your test.

`

Comment: So that worked but now I am getting:     
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <a id="sales...Link" ng-click="consultationClick();" style="cursor: pointer">Consultation</a> is not clickable at point (423, 15). Other element would receive the click: <div id="mainPleaseWait" class="loadingOverlay" style="display: block;">...</div>"

Comment: Make sure that the element is not located into an iFrame, or you added the right condition to wait until element is clickable